# NumPy won't upgrade from 1.5.1 to 1.6.2 on OS X 10.7

Tags: python, numpy, osx-lion, easy-install

I am attempting to update/upgrade my NumPy, but am failing. I think I might have multiple versions of NumPy installed in different directories, but python by default imports an old one. Any help?

Here's where my Python is:

```
Gonzo-vs-Kitties:~ brian$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Here's the version that Python imports:

```
Gonzo-vs-Kitties:~ brian$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.5.1
>>>
```

Now I use easy_install to upgrade NumPy:

```
Gonzo-vs-Kitties:~ brian$ sudo easy_install --upgrade numpy
Searching for numpy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
Reading http://numpy.scipy.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=1369&package_id=175103
Reading http://numeric.scipy.org
Best match: numpy 1.6.2
Processing numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
numpy 1.6.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing f2py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for numpy
Finished processing dependencies for numpy
```

Even after I upgrade, NumPy is still the old version:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.5.1
>>>
```

This is my sys.path:

```
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.7.egg', '/Users/brian/Code/trac/genshi-trunk', '/Users/brian/Code/trac/trac-trunk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually for things like that, virtualenv is amazing. You can just create a new venv and install new version of anything without worrying that stuff is imported properly, conflicts, etc. And if anything goes wrong, its much easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the path of your numpy package:

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

And check whether it is the one you just installed.

Comment: It is not the one I just installed. the __path__ attribute points to '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy'
Ideas on how to address this?

Comment: Remove the old version of numpy, or upgrade it

Comment: When I use pip and/or easy_install to in install,it removes my newer 1.6.2 NumPy and completely ignores the 1.5.1 NumPy. How do I uninstall a version that the uninstaller can't see?

Comment: Depends on how you installed them. Or you can go to that directory and remove it directly.

Comment: I manually removed the directory where the old NumPy was stored. Python now finds the updated NumPy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that it is a **VERY BAD IDEA** to overwrite the `/System/...` numpy, as it may be used internally by the OS. The safest by far is to install numpy locally (ie, from the sources, `python setup.py install --user`), and update your PYTHONPATH so that it captures your local numpy before the system one (just do `PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.x/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`)