# import numpy with python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I installed additional `python 2.7` on my mac and `numpy-1.6.2` for `python 2.7`, however whenever I want to import `numpy`, it will import the `numpy` from the preinstalled `python` version on my Mac, the version is `1.6.1`, can anybody tell me how can I change the import direction to `numpy-1.6.2`??

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure that the library you've just installed and you're trying to import is in your `PYTHONPATH`. Also, doing things like that are not most optimal - consider using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and installing your libraries on per project basis to avoid issues like that and getting a lot more flexibility in managing them.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888679/numpy-wont-upgrade-from-1-5-1-to-1-6-2-on-os-x-10-7) of your numpy package:

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

and then replace the entire contents with the downloaded numpy version 1.6.2, if the stuff in the resulting path looks similar to the numpy 1.6.2 download.

Otherwise just delete that stuff (that's in the path) or uninstall it and remove it through some other way and then use:

```
pip install numpy
```